# jqGrid Bootstrap tooltip not showing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jquery and would like to have a jqGrid tooltip display in the Bootstrap tooltip format.

I am using option

```
guiStyle: "bootstrap",
```

and I am setting the attributes in the loadComplete() function

```
var setTooltipsOnColumnHeader = function (grid, iColumn, text) {
    var thd = jQuery("thead:first", grid[0].grid.hDiv)[0];
    jQuery("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); 
    jQuery("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th:eq(" + iColumn + ")", thd).attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
    jQuery("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th:eq(" + iColumn + ")", thd).attr("title", text);

setTooltipsOnColumnHeader($("#grid"), 9, "Some text is being written to add here");
```

This appears to be working properly as the console view shows this source -

```
<th id="grid_accountvalue" class="ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" title="Some 
text is being written to add here" data-toggle="tooltip" 
aria-selected="true" style="width: 125px;" data-original-title="Some text 
is being written to add here">
```

I have also added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        alert('fire alert');
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    });
</script>
```

to the page and the alert is fired so the tooltip should be initialised.

The bootstrap.css is included in the page.

When I hover over the header I just get a standard tooltip though ?  Any ideas ?

Comment: is ajax involved on this page?

Comment: Yes.  It is doing a $http
  .get("get-data-URL", {timeout: 200000})
  .then(
    function(response) { ...do the code and build the grid...}

Comment: could you please setup an jsFiddle or CodePen (without ajax)?

Comment: $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();    should be placed inside ajax.done. so call this after ajax is complete

Comment: actually I've been a bit of a plonker there, it is inherited code and my first foray in to Angular.  The http.get is an Angular call not a straight AJAX call (getting to the limits of my underlying understanding there).  I suspect if you are right about the ajax solution then the solution may still lie in a proper chaining of functions so that the tooltip initialisation occurs once all other processing / rendering is complete (?!)  I'll try along these lines.